# OpenGL catmull rom spline loop coloring

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, shader, spline

I have a catmull rom spline loop in c++. I able to make the spline and i have the curve points, but when I tried to fill the bordered area with GL_TRIANGLE_FAN I got too much straight line. And my question is, how can I fill the spline loop area with colour efficiently?

This is how I draw the spline:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
unsigned int vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(lines) * sizeof(float), lines, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, vecLinePoints.size());
```

**EDIT:**
This is how I tried to fill my concave polygone:

```
 glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glStencilMask(0xFF);
    glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
    glStencilOp(GL_INVERT, GL_INVERT, GL_INVERT);
    glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);  

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    unsigned int vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(polyPoints) * sizeof(float), polyPoints, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vecPoints.size());

    glStencilMask(0x00);
    glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 0, 0xFF);
    glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

Comment: Is this a closed polygon? Is it convex or concave?

Comment: Yes, it is look like this: https://ibb.co/KXwV47W . But it can be convex or concave, because if I click somewhere the spline change.

Comment: The concept of [Triangle primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) is very simple. The primitives have to be convex.

Comment: And if I want to make a concave polygone?

Comment: `fill the spline loop are with color efficiency` to parse that phrase, I had to turn it into *fill the spline loop area with colour efficiently*.

Comment: You can use the stencil buffer. See [Drawing Filled, Concave Polygons Using the Stencil Buffer](http://what-when-how.com/opengl-programming-guide/drawing-filled-concave-polygons-using-the-stencil-buffer-opengl-programming/)

Comment: Thank you for that! I tried to make it, but I don't know how to use properly the stencil buffer.